# Autocomplete doesn't work for file parameters to jarsigner

Tags: bash, autocomplete, java

I'm using Lubuntu 12.10. Assume I've got a file called test.apk in my current folder.

1.) In LXTerminal/bash if I type,

```
adb install t<TAB>
```

the terminal autocompletes it correctly to "test.apk"

2.) However if I try,

```
jarsigner -verify t<TAB>
```

it doesn't work.

Why is the behavior so? Is it possible to get it to work in the second scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jarsigner` has a completion script in
[bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/). You may be using
bash-completion. Many distributions install it by default. The completion
script for `jarsigner` does some filename filtering. It expects a file with a `.jar` extension. Here is an excerpt from the completion script:

```
# Check if a jar was already given.
local i jar=false
for (( i=0; i < ${#words[@]}-1; i++ )) ; do
    if [[ "${words[i]}" == *.jar && \
        "${words[i-1]}" != -signedjar ]] ; then
        jar=true
        break
    fi
done
...
if ! $jar ; then
...
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '-keystore -storepass -storetype
            -keypass -sigfile -signedjar -digestalg -sigalg -verify
            ...
    _filedir jar
    ...
```

Until a file with a `.jar` extension is given,
[`_filedir`](http://code.google.com/p/bash-completion-lib/source/browse/trunk/include/_filedir?r=86)
and `compgen` are used to restrict completion to jar files and some of the program's flags.

The completion script may be located at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/jarsigner` if you would like to take a look yourself